# Android sending parcelable with setonclickfillinintent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview, parcelable

I got a widget with a listview. Whenever the user presses an item from the listview, i want to receive a Parcelable object compiled in the Adapter of the Widget listview.

So far everything works except that i cannot receive Parcelable objects (everything else works fine)

Adapter:

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    ...
    Intent fillIntent = new Intent();
    fillIntent.putExtra("info", info); //info is a parcelable object
    fillIntent.setData(Uri.parse(fillIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    listViewItem.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_listview_item, fillIntent);
    ...
}
```

Provider:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    ...
    else if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_CLICK_LISTITEM)){
        Info info = intent.getParcelableExtra("info");
        // show details
        if(info != null){
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
            startIntent.putExtra("info", info);
            startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startIntent.setData(Uri.parse(startIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            context.startActivity(startIntent);
        }else{
            Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, "info is null.");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I always log "info is null."...

NOTE: Sending objects of type Info as parcelables to other activities works just fine in my app. I only got problems when sending the **parcelable** object in combination with **setOnClickFillInIntent**.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check your logcat and post any errors you see.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have discovered, this issue is caused by Intent extras being parsed from system process, which does not have appropriate parser to parse custom Parcelable object, see comments for this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6822 for details

As a workaround you could wrap your Parcelable in extra Bundle object, as proposed in comments:

```
Bundle hackBundle = new Bundle();
hackBundle.put("key", myParcelable);
intent.putExtra("bundleKey", hackBundle);
```

It solved the issue in my case